# How observe then write from firebase database consecutively swift

Tags: swift, loops, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observers

I am having trouble observing the current data from firebase, and then take that data add 1 to it and write it back to firebase; but the code I have currently seems to be a never ending loop

```
func likevideoFirebase(row : Int){
    let videoKey = instanceOfUser.myVideos[instanceOfUser.indexNumber].videoKey
    let ref =  Database.database().reference()
    let userKey = instanceOfUser.myVideos
    ref.child("Vidpost").child(videoKey).child("video").child(userKey).child("like").child("count").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in

        var value = snapshot.value as? Int ?? 0
        value += 1; self.instanceOfUser.myVideos[self.instanceOfUser.indexNumber].sentVideo[row].like.numberOfLike  = value

       // this where I set the data I received add 1 to it and use the function below to add it to firebase , but instead it ends up a being a never ending loop  

        self.setliketofirebase(like: value, row: row)
    }
}

func setliketofirebase(like : Int ,row : Int ){
    let videoKey = instanceOfUser.myVideos[instanceOfUser.indexNumber]
    let ref =  Database.database().reference()
    guard let userKey = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
ref.child("Vidpost").child(videoKey).child("video").child(userKey).child("like").child("count").setValue(like)
}
```

Comment: Since you are only doing this once, use .observeSingleEvent to read it. .value leaves an observer on the node and every time it's updated, the closure code will fire (over and over). Also, you may want to build the ref and read from it and then write to it in the same closure - it may be a bit cleaner than a separate function just for one line of code. (it will work either way, just trying to simplify)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code -

```
ref.child("Vidpost").child(videoKey).child("video").child(userKey).child("like").child("count").setValue(like).updateChildValues(["count": like])
```

Every time your previous value is replaced when you using setvalue().

Comment: Thank you , for the help